# Iterate over unknown object attributes in Python

Tags: python, iterator

I have a class as such below. However, the attribute names remain unknown. How, under this circumstance, do a make a class iterator? Basic examples point to `__iter__` and `next()` having some knowledge of the class's attributes as does the example in the [pydocs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#iterators).

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, dictionary):
        for k, v in dictionary.iteritems():
            setattr(self, k, v)
```

I would like to iterate through each object attribute something like so:

```
bar = Foo(dict)
for i in bar:
    bar[i]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @TheSoundDefense suggested you can use the `vars()` built-in to list all the attributes of the object. The following answer extends the idea with an example of using it in your case

**Implementation**

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, dictionary):
        for k, v in dictionary.iteritems():
            setattr(self, k, v)
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(vars(self))
```

**Demo**

```
foo = Foo({'X':1, 'Y':2, 'Z':3})
for elem in foo:
    print elem
```

**Output**

```
Y
X
Z
```

Comment: And I am defeated by an overlong lunch. Good answer.

Answer (score 3):

You may want the `vars()` function here. That will return a dictionary of attribute names and values for any arbitrary object. Just use `vars(obj_name)`.

Comment: Are you suggesting to use `vars()` with the class as part of making the it iterable?

Comment: Yes, to generate the initial dictionary. Then you could iterate over them how you like, probably with `iteritems`. Mainly I was addressing how to obtain the attributes if the names are unknown. I'll post an update when I get back from lunch, unless a better answer comes along.